# loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched after ubuntu update

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I just updated my ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04. When some commands are passed to the terminal after the update I'm getting the following error message.

"CFITSIO.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xde00080, needed 0xcd00080)"

How can I avoid such an error?